# Installing HP ALI Dev on Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

While trying to install HP ALI dev on Eclipse I am getting below:

```
Unable to read repository at https://hpln.hp.com/node/11065/attachment/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I tried by setting Window:>Preferences:>Network Connections:>Active Provider as Manual/Direct/Native. But after attempting in all the ways, I am unable to install HP ALI Dev on my Eclipse.

Comment: Looking at that URL I get an HP login screen, are you logged in before you try and do this install?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way: download the HP ALI plugin zip files then install from the local via Windows->Install New Software